# Extract lines within non standard date range, many dates. Ex: 2015-08-01 17:00:00 to 2015-08-02 05:00

Tags: regex, datetime, text-parsing

It's early, please forgive my lack of verbal finesse.

I have a file containing records I want to subset based upon a date and time range. Specifically from 17:00 on day one to 05:00 on day two, inclusive.

```
UniqueData, 2015-08-01 17:00:00,MiscNotImportantData    
UniqueData, 2015-08-01 17:00:00,MiscNotImportantData    
UniqueData, 2015-08-01 17:00:00,MiscNotImportantData
...
UniqueData, 2015-08-02 05:00:00,MiscNotImportantData    
UniqueData, 2015-08-02 05:00:00,MiscNotImportantData    
UniqueData, 2015-08-02 05:00:00,MiscNotImportantData
```

1. The month does not change.
2. The time increments in 30 second blocks.
3. Eleven records will contain the same date & time, but contain unique data before the date and time.

In the end, what I'd like to have is one file containing records for cycle (Ex: One file with records from 2015-08-01 17:00:00 to 2015-08-02 05:00:00)

My regex/grep/etc foo is weak. An implementation using Java, Perl, or any Linux command line tool would be supremely helpful.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thank you!

Comment: Take a look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32047236/3776858) and [meuh's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32047236/sortf-rfc-dates-using-bash/32047526#32047526). I know you don't want to sort your file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd probably use `awk` for this:

```
awk -F, '$2 >= " 2015-08-01 17:00:00" && $2 <= " 2015-08-02 05:00:00"' data
```

Split the fields on commas.  Observe that the data starts with a blank.  If field two falls in the designated range, print the row of data.

This will work for any validly formatted dates.  If you have a record that contains `2015-08-01 99:99:99`, then that will be selected too.  It doesn't rely on the rows being contiguous in the data file, though it's likely they will be.

Comment: My forehead just met my palm when I realized the $ indicates which token to operate on. Thank you very much!